# Polymorphic Promise in Typescript

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, es6-promise

I'm trying to parameterize a function in a Typescript class that returns a Promise. On completion of the promise, I'm returning `this`, which is used polymorphically by the caller. I'm getting a compile-time error I don't quite understand.

This (trivialized) code compiles fine:

```
class foo {
  aFoo(): Promise<foo> {
    return new Promise<foo>(resolve => resolve(this));
  }
}
class bar extends foo {
  test() {
    this.aFoo().then(result => {
      let val: bar;
      val = result as bar;
    });
  }
}
```

However, I'd rather not have to downcast the results ie. `val = result as bar` every time I call this, so I'm trying to parameterize the function in the superclass:

```
class foo {
  aFoo<T extends foo>(): Promise<T> {
    return new Promise<T>(resolve => resolve(this));
  }
}
class bar extends foo {
  test() {
    this.aFoo<bar>().then(result => {
      let val: bar;
      val = result;
    });
  }
}
```

I'm getting a compiler error on `resolve(this)` in the promise returned from aFoo.

The error says:

```
this: this
Argument of type 'this' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined'.
  Type 'foo' is not assignable to type 'T | PromiseLike<T> | undefined'.
    Type 'foo' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<T>'.
      Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'PromiseLike<T>'.
        Property 'then' is missing in type 'foo' but required in type 'PromiseLike<T>'.ts(2345)
lib.es5.d.ts(1393, 5): 'then' is declared here.
```

I can suppress the compiler error by doing some extraneous casting:

```
return new Promise<foo>(resolve => resolve((this as unknown) as T));
```

I can use the work around, but I'd like to understand what the compiler is objecting to. I thought it might be related to the weirdness of this in JS/TS, but changing this to an arrow function didn't eliminate the error. The error also strikes me odd, in that it is describing this as a type, rather than an instance- but I do see that this can by used in a type context in TS. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Nothing guarantees that `this` is of type `T`. You could use `this.aFoo<SomeOtherType>()`, and `this` would be of type bar, but T would be SomeOtherType.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript has [polymorphic this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) type for this.

You can use `this` as a type, for example to declare something having `Promise<this>` type, and it works as expected:

```
class foo {
  aFoo(): Promise<this> {
    return new Promise<this>(resolve => resolve(this));
  }
}

class bar extends foo {
  test() {
    this.aFoo().then(result => {
      let val: bar;
      val = result;// OK, this is bar here;
    });
  }
}
```